# Запятая перед деепричастным оборотом

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот

*Часто клиенты приходят по рекомендации или увидев работы студии.*

Нужна ли запятая здесь где-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У нас тут нет деепричастного оборота, есть однородные члены предложения, отвечающие на вопрос "как?".

Сказуемое здесь - *приходят по рекомендации или увидев.*

Запятая не нужна.

Вот если б было: "Часто клиенты приходят по рекомендации и, увидев работы студии, в ужасе бегут прочь", речь шла бы о деепричастном обороте, обособляемом.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна: Часто клиенты приходят **по рекомендации или увидев** работы студии.

Здесь **необособленные однородные обстоятельства**, одно из которых выражено падежной формой существительного, а другое - деепричастным оборотом. Обстоятельства связаны одиночным союзом ИЛИ.

**Пояснение** (по теме обособленные и необособленные однородные  обстоятельства, выраженные деепричастиями и деепричастными оборотами)

1) Деепричастные обороты являются в предложении **однородными обстоятельствами**, если они относятся к одному глаголу и следуют друг за другом, раскрывая общую тему.

2) Однородные деепричастные обороты обычно  **обособляются**, так как обозначают добавочное действие,  и разделяются запятыми в большинстве случаев при бессоюзной и союзной связи. В виде исключения они  **не разделяются запятой** при наличии одиночных соединительных или разделительных союзов И/ИЛИ, например:  Осветив  черепицу на крыше и согрев древесину сосны, поднимается выше и выше запоздалое солнце весны.

3)  Однородные обстоятельства, выраженные деепричастиями и деепричастными оборотами, **не обособляются,** если имеют значение обстоятельств образа действия в основном сообщении:  Яков молча, не спеша стал одеваться.

4) Часто обособление отсутствует, если в состав однородного ряда входит **наречие**, особенно  если ряд **начинается с наречия** (или падежной формы существительного):

**Качая головой и с жалостью** на это смотрел Орсини.
Он **вдруг и не объясняя причины** расхохотался совершенно искренне.

Comment: Как вы решили бы вопрос при перестановке этих двух обстоятельств ("или" по другую сторону д. оборота)?

Comment: А  вот пример с обособлением ряда, который начинается с деепричастного оборота и содержит падежную форму существительного: ― Да, дело замечательное, ― ответил тот, качая головой и совершенно двусмысленным тоном. [М. А. Булгаков. Роковые яйца (1924)] .

Comment: Спасибо. Здесь, правда, обстоятельство образа действия, а не причины, как в нашем случае (модифицируется действие глагола "ответил"). Но однородность обстоятельств такая же, и тогда в нашем примере должна появиться одна запятая.

Comment: Часто клиенты приходят,   увидев работы студии или по рекомендации.  Если  ряд начинается  с деепричастного оборота, то  наречие/существительное практически мало  влияют на обособление, сравнить: Часто клиенты приходят,  увидев работы студии.

Comment: У меня сомнения вызывала только мантра об обособлении д. оборота, которое "всегда двусторонне". В найденных вами правилах об опускании одной запятой фигурирует только разделение д. оборотов между собой.

Comment: А теперь уберем  деепричастный оборот, в этом случае обособления нет: "Часто клиенты приходят по рекомендации". Поэтому нет обособления, если мы его добавляем, но ставим  на второе место.

Comment: Его нет только из-за союза, а можно ведь добавить два и более одн. обстоятельства в разных формах, с союзом и/или перед последним. Все (кроме последнего) будут разделены запятыми.

Comment: Лучше говорить не о постановке запятых, а об обособлении или необособлении всего ряда. А далее, внутри этого ряда, будут действовать обычные правила для однородных членов, зависящие от вида союзов.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна, это понятно. Её просто негде ставить. Деепричастный оборот **обособляятся**, а не отделяется, поэтому запятые если ставятся, то с двух сторон. А перед "или" запятая невозможна.

Вот как быэто корректно сформулировать, чтобы не "от противного" и не очень "учебникам" перечить...

Тут начинается терминологическая чехарда. Попробуем разобраться.
1) Имеет ли место "адвербализация" деепричастия? Вряд ли. Во-первых это происходит почти исключительно с одиночными деепричастиями в соответствующем наречном значении. У нас нет ни того признака. В усеченной фразе *"часто клиенты приходят(,) увидев работы студии"* обосновать отсутствие запятой и наречность оборота было бы непросто.
2) По тем же мотивам говорить об отсутствии тут деепричастного оборота тоже будет некорректно. Он есть как таковой, но спрятан в ряду однородных определений выраженных разными частями речи.

***В таком ряду однородных членов деепричастный оборот теряет свою непосредственную грамматическую связь с глаголом и на этом основании не может быть обособлен.***

Формулировка "нет деепричастного оборота" мне не нравится: как же это "нет", когда он налицо?

Думаю, что ни против отсутствия необходимости в запятых, ни против моей формулировки возражений особых не последует, хотя Розенталь формулирует это в несколько других терминах.

> [деепричастный оборот не обособляется]
>   ...
>   6) если деепричастный оборот
>   или одиночное деепричастие выступает в качестве однородного члена
>   предложения с необособленным обстоятельством: *Алёша длинно и как-то
>   прищурив глаза посмотрел на Ракитина (Дост.); …Вдруг завопила она
>   раздирающим воплем и залившись слезами (Дост.); Остановив Власову, он
>   одним дыханием и не ожидая ответов закидал её трескучими и сухими
>   словами (М. Г.); Клим Самгин шагал по улице бодро и не уступая дорогу
>   встречным людям (М. Г.); Он долго и нимало не стесняясь подробностями
>   объяснял, почему именно монашек мог быть родителем Иванушки (М. Г.);
>   Сначала Мишка снимал танки лёжа и сидя на корточках (Сим.); Он
>   научился решать задачи быстро и не прибегая к справочникам; Мальчик
>   стоял неподвижно и не спуская глаз с собаки; Спокойно и не глядя ни на
>   кого она продолжала свой рассказ; Дворник с недоумением и нахмурясь
>   разглядывал Раскольникова (Дост.); Князь Андрей взглянул на Тимохина,
>   который испуганно и недоумевая смотрел на своего командира (Л. Т.);
>   Веретёна с разных сторон равномерно и не умолкая шумели (Л. Т.); К
>   дверям кабинета все подходили обыкновенно перешёптываясь и на цыпочках
>   (Л. Т.); Тот ему отвечал не смущаясь и откровенно (Пом.)*.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=80#pp80

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна, но не по причине особенностей самого деепричастного оборота: не будь второго основания для "прихода" (по рекомендации), сам по себе этот оборот (с обстоятельственным значением причины) был бы обособлен.

> Часто клиенты приходят [к нам], увидев работы студии [в рекламе, и
>   остаются довольны выполненными заказами].

*(ср. Я знаю – солнце померкло б, увидев наших душ золотые россыпи. [Маяковский])*

В нашем случае через "или" объединены в перечислительный ряд **два обстоятельства причины**: одно выражено существительным и само по себе не требует отделения запятой, второе - деепричастным оборотом с обстоятельственным значением причины. Это "или" в  рамках перечисления и убирает запятую. При перестановке деепричастного оборота запятая появится перед ним:

> Часто клиенты приходят, увидев работы студии (, ознакомившись с
>   рекламными материалами) или по рекомендации.

Answer (score 0):

Деепричастный оборот, конечно же, есть, ведь у деепричастия есть зависимые слова. Но принцип однородности, безусловно, работает. Поэтому запятая не нужна.